# Generate random date ranges where range size is decided from discrete distribution

Tags: scala

I have the following function to generate a random date between two dates:

```
val random = new Random(System.nanoTime)
def randomStartTime(days: Integer): LocalDateTime = {
  // Uses to=today and randomly selects a from day maximum days back in time
  val to = LocalDateTime.now()  
  val from = to.minusDays(days) 
  val diff = SECONDS.between(from, to)     
  from.plusSeconds(random.nextInt(diff.toInt))
}
```

Now I try to write a function that returns a start and end date with a diff between start and stop of size x. I want x to be selected from a discrete distribution that I can specify, for example:

```
singleDay = .4
week = .1
month = .1
twoMonths = .1
year = .1
3Years = .1
over3Years = .1
```

This says that there is a 40% chance of a date range diffing with 1day.

ALSO

the signature of the function should be `dateRange(endDate: LocalDate, daysBack: Integer)`

For example I send in `dateRange("2016-04-03", 600)`, now return a daterange of size x between `2016-04-03 - 600days AND 2016-04-03` This adds the problem of some ranges are not possible to produce at all if the range is to narrow, for example the 3year range in this example.

The question I have is how this should be done in Scala, the problem im having is how to construct a descrite distribution in an idiomatic way and how to constrain the range based on the allowed input range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
def dateRange(date : String, daysBack : Int) : Int =
{
    val listAvailable = List(1,7,daysInMonth(date), daysInTwoMonth(date), 365, 1095, 1095 + Math.abs(Random.nextInt)).filter(_ < daysBack)
    val listDistribution = List(40.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0).take(listAvailable.size)
    val maxDistribution = listDistribution.sum
    val listDistributionUpdated = listDistribution.map{distribution => (distribution * 100) / maxDistribution}
    val value = Random.nextInt(100).toDouble
    var index = 0
    var found = false
    var foundIndex = 0
    var sumValue = 0.0
    while(index < listDistribution.size && !found)
    {
        sumValue = sumValue + listDistribution(index)
        if(sumValue >= value)
        {
            found = true
            foundIndex = index 
        }
        index = index + 1
    }

    listAvailable(foundIndex)
}

def daysInMonth(date String): Int =
{
 //implement according to date 30 or 31
}

def daysInTwoMonth(date String): Int =
{
 //implement
}
```